# Spring Security BadCredentialsException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am following [this Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt), and I can't see any differences (except maybe the pregenerated login page template), but I still get a `BadCredentialsException` when trying to login with a hard-coded user/password combo, which I've already confirmed is in the DB and the password in there is encrypted.

Here's my code, let me know if more is needed:

SecurityConfig:

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/action/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/action_template/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login-error");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

MyUserDetailsService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                    "No user found with username: " + email);
        }

        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach((r) -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r)));

        return  new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getEmail(),
                user.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                authorities
        );
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the stacktrace

```
2018-11-14 13:52:05.785 DEBUG 2100 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've also edited my SecurityConfig and added `.antMatchers("/error").permitAll()`, but it didn't help

**EDIT 2:**

Here's the [Github repo](https://github.com/VicenteRD/TrackerDNA), it should provide more insight.
I have no clue on how to diagnose this further...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm... perplexed.
I've found the issue. I don't know why I thought it was ok to keep it and I don't know why the tutorial has it there, but even if the password is 'password', `user.getPassword().toLowerCase()` is lowercasing the BCrypt hash, not the actual password.
Removing `.toLowerCase()` fixes it.

Comment: lol, I haven't notice that. You should still consider simplifying the configuration as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot can pick up/create all the necessary beans automatically, so you can simplify the SecurityConfig like this (It will find your UserDetailsService and will create a default DaoAuthenticationProvider if there is no such bean defined):

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/action/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/action_template/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login-error");
    }

}
```

Also define the passwordEncoder bean in a different configuration class (However I'm not absolutely sure if it's also needed) :

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Comment: I've fixed it ;) Thanks for the tip either way, I'll test what you said about the `UserDetailsService`!

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like is related to the way you are registering your password encoded. Try to register it like this:

```
@Autowired
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

     auth
          .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
          .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}
```

Comment: Where did you place that ?

Comment: In `configure(HttpSecurity http)`, after `.antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()`

Comment: No success yet... Should I make the Github repo public and link that?